# Cloning divs on click with a remove button - But how do i hide the remove button on the initial clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

So I have a large button on the left and a form on the right. When you click the button it creates up to 5 additional forms. It also updates the id's and the flavor profile # text.

Its still a little buggy and was looking for some help sorting it out as im not the best with JS.

**Problem 1:** If you create the 5 additional clones and then delete them. When you create them again it labels them as #7 #8 #9 - Since *only 6 forms are allowed.* I need this number to *only display 1-6 and not go above or below.* I would like the same thing for the id's too.

**Problem 2:** Another issue I have is i would like to remove the *"Remove button"* from *Flavor Profile #1* (The first form). Because if all the forms are deleted there is nothing left to clone.

Thanks for any help!

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1902/)**

```
var cloneIndex = 1;
var clones_limit = 5;
var cloned_nbr = $(".clonedInput").length-1; //Exclude Default (first) div 

function clone()
{
  if(cloned_nbr<clones_limit)
  {
    cloneIndex++;
    cloned_nbr++;

    var new_clone =  $(".clonedInput").first().clone();

    new_clone.attr("id", "clonedInput" +  cloneIndex);
    new_clone.find(".label-nbr").text(cloneIndex);
    new_clone.find(".category").attr("id","category"+cloneIndex);
    new_clone.show(".remove").attr("id","remove"+cloneIndex);
    new_clone.on('click', 'button.clone', clone);
    new_clone.on('click', 'button.remove', remove);

    $("#formy").append(new_clone);
  }
}
function remove(){
  if(cloneIndex>1){
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    cloned_nbr--;
  }
}
$(".clone").on("click", clone);

$(".remove").on("click", remove);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it up a bit. It should work with proper indexes and remove buttons!

```
function getFreeIds() {
    var used = $('.clonedInput').find('.label-nbr').map(function(i, v) {
            return parseInt(v.innerText)
        }).get();
    return allowed.filter(function (i) {return used.indexOf(i) === -1});
}
```

It does what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1921/

Comment: Ha ha no issues...you edited it 4-5 times I guess!! got confused, cheers

Comment: looks better, will it be better if you put a renumbering function at the end of remove?? 1,2,3,4 on remove 1 and add gives 2,3,4,1 now....it would be nice to get it sorted...nice solution though (y)

Comment: We can't do everything for him haha, he still needs to learn :)

Comment: I am totally fine with you doing everything for me! :D Ill turn it into another question if you prefer. xD

Answer (score 1):

Add a function that checks the number of removable `div`s present. If its more than 1, display the remove button, else don't:

```
function handleRemoveButton(){
    var numItems = $('.clonedInput').length;
    if(numItems<=1){
        $(".remove").hide();
    }
    else{
        $(".remove").show();
    }
}
```

And call it thrice : once on `$(document).ready();` and once at the last of `clone(){}` and `remove()`.

Comment: Not sure how to add to my pre-existing code to be honest. Just attempted with no luck.

Comment: Can you re-post my JS fiddle with your changes? :)

Comment: Thanks!! :) (is there a way for me to hide the actual button all together on the first one?)

Answer (score 1):

write a rearrange function to update the content and call it from when you are cloning an item or removing it

```
function rearrange(){
    var count = 1;
    var totalCount = $(".clonedInput").length;
    $(".clonedInput").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id", "clonedInput"+count).find(".label-nbr").text(count).end().
        find(".category").attr("id","category"+count).end().find(".remove").toggle(totalCount!=1).attr("id","remove"+count).on("click", remove);
        count++;
    });
}
```

Check the jsfiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1922/

Comment: Welcome! its great that it helped you.